# Refresh div (Wordpress comments) with ajax

Tags: ajax

What I'd like to do is have a button that you can click to refresh the comments section without reloading the page.
This seems like it should be simple to do, but I just can't get my head around Ajax.

(no button just yet, just an interval)

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".commentswrapper").load("html");
}, 10000);


Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    
localhost:8888/post-title/html
```

(http:// omitted from link because SO won't let me wrap it in code tags or post it otherwise)

Shouldn't that just refresh the html of that div?

Answer (score 0):

The jquery load method requests a page of HTML and puts it in your div. the parameter you give is a URL from your server. In your example, it is requesting a URL of "HTML", which doesn't exist in Wordpress.

To get this working, you would have to write a new server script, e.g. Getcomments.php which returns the comments for the current page.

This isn't trivial unless you've done some server side programming in php and are familiar with the Wordpress codex,